# Where to store multi-tenant user specified cache?

Tags: symfony, caching, saas

I'm building SaaS application on top of Symfony2. 
Our system is simple: one node balancer, a few application servers, and a few database servers.

Every app server has exactly same copy of app and differents only in parameters.

- Where to store client specified cache?
- Where to store `app/cache`? Separate for every client `app/cache/clientN`?
- Where to store HTTP cache? On app servers or node balancer?
  What if every client has different domain?
- Where to store database query/result cache? On DB server in memory (redis/riak/memcached)?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of that can be served by the same cluster of distributed HA cache. There are many. Redis/Hazelcast are examples of HA cache. You only need to take care of cache grouping/naming.

> Where to store client specified cache?

I do not understand what is client specified cache.

> Where to store app/cache? Separate for every client app/cache/clientN?

Same cache can be used. Ensure that cache naming is different for different entities. Separate cache or same is a specific question. This depends on the extent of separation desired. Also on the size of each cache, how it impacts other clients etc. This is similar to whether you want a shared table or a shared db or separate db server for the multi-tenant implementation.

> Where to store HTTP cache? On app servers or node balancer? What if
>   every client has different domain?

Static content can be cached on node balancer. Load balancers like nginx support this capability. The same cache server can be used too.

> Where to store database query/result cache? On DB server in memory
>   (redis/riak/memcached)?

Again, the same cache cluster can be used. Note memcached is not replicated. Custom app code is required for that.